# background image is not showing on mobile but showing on desktop also showing on mobile incognito

Tags: html, css, image, css-position, fixed

[This](https://www.awaitingadventures.in) is my website. In customize a tour section the background image is fixed and it's showing and loading in desktop all browser but in every mobile browser it's not showing except mobile incognito.

```
  <div class="container text-center" data-aos="zoom-in">
    <h3>Customize Your Tour Now </h3>
    <p> </p>
    <a class="cta-btn"  href="/enquiry" style="text-decoration: none;">Let's Go</a>
  </div>
```

this is the HTML code

```
#call-to-action {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 142, 99, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), url(../../img/callbg)fixed center center ; </br>


  background-size:cover;
  margin:80px 0 120px 0;


kindly help thannks 
  padding:90px 0;
  
}

#call-to-action h3 {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: 1000;
}

#call-to-action p {
  color: #fff;
}

#call-to-action .cta-btn {
 
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 28px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  color: #000;
}

#call-to-action .cta-btn:hover {
  background:#1da1f2;
  border: 2px solid #1da1f2;
}
```

Comment: 90% it's just cache 'problem'. i can see bg.

Comment: Your SSL certificate appears to be self-signed. Don’t expect that to work everywhere “in the wild”.

Comment: its not the cache problem even after clearing cache and cookies its not showing on mobile..or if its showed for the first time then again next time when i am revisiting the website its not showing

Comment: You don’t appear to be automatically redirecting to the HTTPS version, so I’d first of all check if the problem appears the same way, when you access it via HTTP only.